# Programmatically detect pagebreak on insert

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am programming a macro for word 2010 for formatting a document. If tables are inserted and spread over more than one page, I want that the table headers are repeated on each page. On the next page I also want to repeat the caption of the table and add a "(cont.)" at the end.

[image: Somethink linke this...]

Unfortunately, there is no automatic solution by Word neither to repeat the table caption nor editing them. So I came to the conclusion that this will only be possible if I split the table. But that's okay...

Now my question: Is it somehow possible to recognize in my vba code if a page break has been performed during my insert procedure?

Comment: Does the table have to be in Word?  Excel has a built in program for adding title to each "page" on print.

Comment: Might help if you add your Macro to the question for everyone to see

Comment: There is no macro yet. I have this problem, as described. And I can sovle it, if I find a way to programmatically detect pagebreaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found some solution. It's definitely not nice, but it could work.

I am saving the page number before the insert and then compare it to the page number after the insert.

```
Sub insert()
    Dim currentPage
    currentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    Selection.InsertFile ("Filepath")
    If (Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) <> currentPage) Then
        ' Page break

    End If
End Sub
```